# No 37 question in knight of pi math tournament Dec 15, 2012

Tags: contest-math

The five digit integer ABCDE, where each letter represents a digit, not necessary distinct, is divided by the numbers $2$,$3$,$4$,$5$, and $6$. The remainders are A, B, C, D, and E respectively. What is the integer ABCDE?

Thanks.

Comment: Does "five digit number" mean $A>0$?

Comment: If $A=0$ is allowed, I suppose $A=B=C=D=E=0$ is a trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $A=1$ ,there are $3$ possible values for $E$ since $E$ is odd and between $0$ and $5$. once $E$ has been fixed we can easily obtain $D$. once $D$ has been obtained we have the last two digits so we can obtain $C$. Also notice from $E$ you can obtain $B$ immediately.

Thus there are three cases(three possible values of $E$), they are:

$11311$ This one works

$10133$ This one doesn't work since the number is not a multiple of three

$12105$ This one doesn't work since the number is a multiple of three

Comment: I obtained these numbers by writing $E$ and then deducing $D$, then deducing $C$, and then deducing $B$, until the number was complete.

Comment: Oops, thank you Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

$A=1$, because it won't be a five digit number if $A=0$ and those are the only remainders when dividing by $2$.  $C$ and $E$ are then odd, $C=1,3$ and $E=1,3,5$.  $B\lt 3$ and $D\lt 5$  We are down to $90$ possibilities, within range of brute force on a contest.

Comment: Of course, if you know $E$, you know $B$. $(E,B)=(1,1), (3,0),$ or $(5,2)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Good point.  That gets us down to $30$.

Comment: And $D$ is also entirely determined by $E$ for different reasons, since modulo $5$, none of the other digits matter. Down to $6$. So $(E,B,D)=(1,1,1),(3,0,3),$ or $(5,2,0)$.